# Can't run programs, which were installed with ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, installed-programs

I can't run programs, which were installed with ubuntu software center. It was working earlier, but now, I can only watch pulsing icon on side bar, and after a few second it disappears. For example telegram, webstorm, phpstorm and others.
Help please

Comment: What error message do you get if you run the program on the command line?

Comment: Command: $ sudo phpstorm
Response: /var has 'other' write 40777

Comment: Related: [Snap applications installed via Ubuntu/GNOME Software aren't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967790/snap-applications-installed-via-ubuntu-gnome-software-arent-working)

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to Ubuntu, so I can ask really stupid questions =)

Comment: There really is never a stupid question here, everyone started as a beginner and had to learn. I do not have a answer for you but the information I asked from you and the related link I commented will be helpful to someone that is more knowledgeable than me. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!